# SAP UI5: Re-align simple form label and fields to left side

Tags: sapui5

I need to move all these highlighted elements to left side of the page(Screen attached). Below is the code for simple form in my xml view:

<---XML View--->

```html
<f:SimpleForm id="SimpleFormDisplay354" minWidth="1024" maxContainerCols="3" editable="false" layout="ResponsiveGridLayout"
    title="{i18n>searchFormTitle}" labelSpanL="3" labelSpanM="3" emptySpanL="4" emptySpanM="4" columnsL="1" columnsM="1">
    <f:content>
     <Label text="{i18n>labelDate}" labelFor="datePickerId" design="Bold" >
      <layoutData>
       <l:GridData span="L2 M3 S6"/>
      </layoutData>
     </Label>
     <DatePicker id="datePickerId" visible="true" displayFormat="MMM dd,yyyy" valueFormat="dd-MM-yyyy" placeholder="{i18n>dateInput}"
      change="handleChange">
      <layoutData>
       <l:GridData span="L2 M3 S6"/>
      </layoutData>
     </DatePicker>
     <Button text="{i18n>search}" id="searchButton" width="50%" type="Emphasized" class="Button" press="OnDateSearch">
      <layoutData>
       <l:GridData span="L2 M3 S6"/>
      </layoutData>
     </Button>
    </f:content>
   </f:SimpleForm>
```

Can anyone help me with what GridData span setting I should make in order to move these elements to left most corner?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U5uF7.png)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use the existing properties for the Grid Data, you can use `indentL` property.

```
<Label text="{i18n>labelDate}" labelFor="datePickerId" design="Bold" >
    <layoutData>
        <l:GridData span="L1 M3 S6" indentL="0"/>
    </layoutData>
</Label>
```

Give one column (out of 12) to your label and then indent it to 0 (span value=0 for the Large screen), similarly, you can do it for different screen sizes.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set labelSpanL/labelSpanM to 1 or 2 to decrease left space, but SimpleForm always align the label to right and put colon ":" between Label and Control.

If labelSpan 1 or 2 dont resolve. The only way i know is trying use CSS.